# logstash iptables log parse

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

ELK run in containers

I setup iptables send all input/forward/output logs to logstash.
example log seen on kibana discover pane.

```
@version:1 host:3.3.3.3 @timestamp:March 3rd 2018, 12:14:45.220 message:<4>Mar 3 20:14:47 myhost kernel: [2242132.946331] LOG_ALL_TRAF public INPUT IN=public OUT= MAC=00:1e:67:f2:db:28:00:1e:67:f2:d9:7c:08:00 SRC=1.1.1.1 DST=2.2.2.2 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=17722 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=3504 DPT=8080 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 type:rsyslog tags:_jsonparsefailure _id:AWHtgJ_qYRe3mIjckQsb _type:rsyslog _index:logstash-2018.03.03 _score: -
```

The entire log is categorized as 'message' field.

I want to use SRC, DST, SPT, DPT etc as each individual field and then also use them to visualize.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to learn about Grok filter plugin that will enable you split the message into named fields.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

The list of common patterns is available [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).
And you can test your patterns [here](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match).